# Is there a way to distinguish between and IMAP namespace and an IMAP mailbox in results of PHP's imap_getmailboxes()

Tags: php, namespaces, imap, prefix

When using PHP's function...

```
imap_getmailboxes($imap_connection, '{domain.tld:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}', '%');
```

... with `$pattern` set to `%` *(only return results of current level)* and `$reference` set to only the server reference with **no** mailbox name specified *(root level)*, one would expect to only receive the accounts `namespace` records... however since some clients/servers allow mailboxes to be added as root level mailboxes without a `prefix / namespace`, there is no guarantee.

My question is, **is it possible to identify if a result is either a mailbox, or a namespace/prefix?**

The *attributes* bitmask returned with each result only includes a mix of the following flags:

```
LATT_NOINFERIORS = 1
LATT_NOSELECT = 2
LATT_MARKED = 4
LATT_UNMARKED = 8
LATT_REFERRAL = 16
LATT_HASCHILDREN = 32
LATT_HASNOCHILDREN = 64
```

... and the `INBOX` namespace in my example only ever returns a value of 32 (`LATT_HASCHILDREN`).  Is there any other way to achieve this identification or another function that differentiates?

Comment: If the server supports the `NAMESPACE` extension, you an run the `NAMESPACE` command to get a list of the critical namespaces. (RFC 2342)

Comment: @Max But how is the question, I don't see a PHP function that supports this unless I've missed it, so am I going to have to script a whole socket based approach to this?  Seems odd that with all the PHP IMAP functions that exist, that this isn't directly supported...

Comment: The PHP IMAP extension is unfortunately based on a kind of ancient c library, and so appears to be extremely difficult to extend it.  Do you have to use php_imap.so?  Can you consider other libraries or environments?

Comment: @Max This was such a high level one-off application, I was just hoping for a quick fix, but alas, I have a growing wish list so a move to the horde client library is probably worth the effort.  Appreciate your help!